# Why is my Java while loop making two passes first?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Why is my while loop making two passes before allowing user input? Tried the same with for loop and can't figure out why it's asks for input twice before allowing user to enter input. I know it's a stupid, simple logic mistake I'm making but I'm a noob. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How large would you like the array to be? (number)");
    int arraySize = scan.nextInt();
    String [] myArray = new String [arraySize];
    int i = 0;

    if (arraySize <= 0 ) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer for the array size. Rerun program when ready.");
    } else {
        while (i < myArray.length) {
            System.out.println("Please type a string to be entered in the array");
            myArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
    }


}
```

Output looks like

```
How large would you like the array to be? (number)
5
Please type a string to be entered in the array
Please type a string to be entered in the array
```

Comment: nextInt() might leave a character in the buffer, so that's immediately picked up by the nextLine()

Comment: Check to see if `myArray[0]` is 5.

Comment: @Ben very close. You forgot about the break line character that is being read by `Scanner#nextLine`.

Comment: I knew it was something like that. Gah I hate user input :)

Comment: Also good practice to call scan.close() when you're done

Comment: I recommend taking all input as strings and deal with it. It can save headaches when users make mistakes at the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `scan.nextLine();` right after your `nextInt`:

```
int arraySize = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

The first iteration of the `while` loop is not blocking on the `nextLine()` because it is picking the new line after the first integer that you input.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How large would you like the array to be? (number)");
    int arraySize = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); // This advances the Scanner to the next line.
    String [] myArray = new String [arraySize];
    int i = 0;

    if (arraySize <= 0 ) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer for the array size. Rerun program when ready.");
    } else {
        while (i < myArray.length) {
            System.out.println("Please type a string to be entered in the array");
            myArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
    }


}
```